# difference between function hiding and overloading

Tags: c++, oop, visual-c++

I can't find any difference between function hiding and overloading. As the function hiding is the function that is present in derived class and hides the function of a base class. Having same name of the function in both of them. 
Overloading: having same name but different signature in both derived and base class.

```
class A {
    void print(int);
};
class B: public A {
    void print(float);
};
```

does it hide function or overload ?

Comment: Neither.   Even if we assume `Class` is a typo and should be `class`, the functions are `private`, and neither class has another member function or friend, so neither function can be called by any function other than itself.

Comment: @Pi Question is about *overloading* vs. hiding, not *overriding* vs. hiding. Two completely different concepts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function `B::print` *hides* the parent function `A::print`.

If you want to *overload* you need to pull in the `A::print` function into the scope of `B`:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    using A::print;  // Pull in (all) A::print symbols into the scope of B

    void print(float);  // Now overloads A::print
};
```

Answer (score 4):

A name defined in a scope **hides** declarations of the same name in any outer scope. Like this:

```
int name; // global name

void f() {
    int name; // name 1, hides global name
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) }
        int name; // name 2, hides name 1 and global name
        name = 3; // assigns 3 to name 2
    }
    name = 4; // assigns 4 to name 1
}

int other = name; // copies value of global name into other
```

When two or more functions with the same name are declared **in the same scope**, the name is overloaded:

```
// two functions in global scope:
void f();
void f(int);

void g() {
    f();  // ok: calls first version of f
    f(1); // ok: calls second version of f
}
```

Definitions in different scopes **do not define overload sets**, because the declaration in the inner scope hides the same name in any outer scope.

```
class cl1 {
public:
    // hides global f's:
    void f();

    void g() {
        f();  // ok: calls cl1::f()
        f(1); // error: no f takes an int; global f(int) is hidden
    }
};
```

Of course, defining more than one function in the same scope still defines overloads, even if there are functions with the same (hidden) name in an outer scope.

```
class cl2 {
public:
    // these hide global f's, and provided overloads:
    void f();
    void f(int);

    void g() {
        f();  // calls cl2::f()
        f(1); // calls cl2::f(int)
    }
};
```

A class definition provides a new scope, so the rules about name hiding and overloading apply to names defined in the class.

```
class cl3 : public cl2 {
        void g() {
            f();  // calls cl2::f()
            f(1); // calls cl2::f(int)
        }
    };

class cl4 : public cl2 {
    // hides all f's:
    void f();

    void g() {
        f();  // ok: calls cl4::f();
        f(3); // error: no f takes an int; global f(int) and cl2::f(int) are hidden
    }
};

class cl5 : public cl2 {
    // hides all f's and provides overloads:
    void f();
    void f(int);

    void g() {
        f();  // ok: calls cl5::f()
        f(3); // ok: calls cl5::f(int)
    }
};
```

You can also use a signature that doesn't match any of the signatures in the base class. After all, the name of those base class functions is hidden.

```
class cl5 : public cl2 {
public:
    // hides all f's:
    void f(std::string);

    void g() {
        f();       // error: no f taking no arguments
        f(3);      // error: no f taking int
        std::string arg("test");
        f(arg); // ok: calls cl5::f(std::string)
    }
};
```

And, finally, if you want to write a derived class that adds signatures to the set of overloaded functions defined in a base class, you have to add the name of those overloaded functions to the derived class:

```
class cl6 : public cl2 {
public:
    using cl2::f;        // pull cl2::f into current scope
    void f(std::string); // add overload to names from cl2

    void g() {
        f();    // ok: calls cl2::f()
        f(3);   // ok: calls cl2::f(int)
        std::string arg("test");
        f(arg); // ok: calls cl6::f(std::string)
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice explanation. If you can explain Argument Dependent Lookup and Global Scope, this explanation could be more enlighting.